# Conditional independence.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

I am trying to understand the sentence, "X and Z are independent given Y". I think this means that $X|Y$ is independent of $Z|Y$. Is this the same thing as saying $X|(Y,Z)$ only depends on $Y$? This is basically saying that once $(Y,Z)$ takes on a value, we don't care about what $Z$ takes on since $X$ doesn't depend on $Z$ once $Y$ occurs. How do I prove this rigorously?

Comment: I cannot provide a rigorous proof for you but in case you want an intuitive understand then you could watch this instead https://youtu.be/zpELC6i90Sc

Answer (score 1):

If $X \perp \!\!\! \perp Z$ given $Y$ then yes that means $(X \mid Y) \perp \!\!\! \perp (Z \mid Y)$

(read $A \perp \!\!\! \perp B $ as 'A is independent of B'.)

Moreover we have $P(X \cap Z \mid Y) = P(X \mid Y) \cdot P(Z \mid Y)$

So if we additionally condition on $Z$ : $\displaystyle P(X \mid Z,Y) = \frac{P(X \cap Z \mid Y)}{P(Z)} = \frac{P(X \cap Z \cap Y)}{P(Z)P(Y)} = \frac{P(X \cap Y \mid Z)}{P(Y)}$

**Note: this of course this requires that** $P(Y), P(Z) > 0$

Interestingly enough in the case where we condition $X$ upon $Z$ and $Y$, it turns out it does not matter the order in which we condition.

Comment: Yes, I understood that much as well! but unfortunately we need to get rid of all instances $Z$ in order to claim that $X|(Y,Z)$ only depends on $Y$.

Comment: based on your expression of $P(X|Z,Y)$ we need it to equal $P(X|Y)$ which we would get if only we can get rid of that $Z$ in the final line.

Comment: Yes, if we want $(X\mid Y) \perp \!\!\! \perp Z$ we need $P(X \mid Y,Z) = P(X|Y)$ as you have stated. So from the assumption made by your post we have $P(X \cap Y \cap Z) = P[(X \cap Y) \cap (Z \cap Y) ]= P(X \cap Y) \cdot P(Z \cap Y)$ but not necessarily $P(X)\cdot P(Z \cap Y)$ nor $P(X \cap Y) \cdot P(Z)$

Comment: I see, so my claim that $X|(Y,Z)$ only depends on $Y$ is equivalent to $X$ and $Z$ being conditionally independent given $Y$ is actually wrong then?

Comment: If we want it to only depend on $Y$ then from the above we would need that $Z$ has no effect on $X$ but also has no effect on $Y$.

Comment: The situation you are after would be that $(X \mid Y) \perp \!\!\! \perp Z$ : i.e. $X$ conditioned upon by $Y$ gives a new random variable which is independent of $Z$.